# How server response can satisfy dataSource.transport.create?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using kendoGrid and my remote data is from php.

this is an example of the grid:

```
$('#grid').kendoGrid({
    columns: [
        {field: 'Agent_Code', title: 'Agent code'},
        {field: 'Agent_Name', title: 'Agent name'},
        {field: 'Short_Name', title: 'Short name'},
        {field: 'More_Info',  title: 'More info'},
        {command: {name: 'edit'}}
    ],
    toolbar: [
        {name: 'create'}
    ],
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            create: {
                url: 'ajax/create.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json'
            },
            read: {
                url: 'ajax/read.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json'
            },
            update: {
                url: 'ajax/update.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json'
            },
            destroy: {
            },
        },
        schema: {
            type: 'json',
            data: 'data.results',
            model: {
                id: 'Agent_Code',
                fields: {
                    Agent_Code: {editable: true, nullable: false, type: 'string'},
                    Agent_Name: {editable: true, nullable: false, type: 'string'},
                    Short_Name: {editable: true, nullable: false, type: 'string'},
                    More_Info:  {editable: true, nullable: false, type: 'string'}
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The grid populates correctly because I set "dataSource.schema.data" to "data.results" so the grid know how to locate the data at the server response. 
server 'json' response structure for "transport.read" is:

```
{
    code: 'ok',
    data: {
        id: [' ', ' '],
        results: [
            {Agent_Code: ' ', Agent_Name: ' ', Short_Name: ' ', More_Info: ' '},
            {Agent_Code: ' ', Agent_Name: ' ', Short_Name: ' ', More_Info: ' '}
        ]
    }
}
```

My problem is that I don't understand how to do that for "dataSource.transport.create" and "dataSource.transport.update" the server receive the data correctly, store it to DB and response with:

```
{
    code: 'ok',
    text: 'operation succeeded'
}
```

but the grid don't understand that everything is OK and update the grid.

What is missing here?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your `schema` definition adding `errors` to it.

```
schema   : {
    type : 'json',
    data : 'data.results',
    model: {
        id    : 'Agent_Code',
        fields: {
            Agent_Code: {editable: true, nullable: false, type: 'string'},
            Agent_Name: {editable: true, nullable: false, type: 'string'},
            Short_Name: {editable: true, nullable: false, type: 'string'},
            More_Info : {editable: true, nullable: false, type: 'string'}
        }
    },
    errors : function(a) {
        return a.code !== "ok";
    }
}
```

This `errors` function returns `true` or `false` depending on `code`.

In addition and since you seems to do not return the record when it is updated or inserted, you should modify `data` to do not try to find it when `update` or `create` but find it when `read`.

You might define it as:

```
data : function (a) {
    if (a.data && a.data.results){
        return a.data.results;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
},
```

Now, the schema definition would be:

```
schema   : {
    type : 'json',
    data : function (a) {
        if (a.data && a.data.results){
            return a.data.results;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    },
    model: {
        id    : 'Agent_Code',
        fields: {
            Agent_Code: {editable: true, nullable: false, type: 'string'},
            Agent_Name: {editable: true, nullable: false, type: 'string'},
            Short_Name: {editable: true, nullable: false, type: 'string'},
            More_Info : {editable: true, nullable: false, type: 'string'}
        }
    },
    errors : function(a) {
        return a.code !== "ok";
    }
}
```

*NOTE:* If you always return `ok` then you might avoid defining `errors`, the only important part is redefining `data`.

**EDIT**: You can read more in KendoUI site:

1. About using it [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/ASP.NET/Hello%20Kendo%20UI/asp-net-hello-kendo-ui-part-2) and specifically on using `errors` and `error` [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/ASP.NET/Hello%20Kendo%20UI/asp-net-hello-kendo-ui-part-2#map-the-errors-field-in-the-schema).
2. You can also check [`DataSource.schema.errors`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.errors) documentation and `DataSource.error`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#events-error) event handler documentation.

Comment: I didn't understand why the if statement contains **a.data &&**. Additionaly, can you point me to documentation regarding this issue I didn't found any at kendoui website

Comment: I check for `a.data` because when the server send the result to the `update` the JSON does not include it but this is executed anyway so it prevents from crashing. Then I check for `a.data.results` because here is where the information is actually coming. Yes, I might have checked only for the first condition hoping that the message is well formed but I did prefer to do this since it is more secure. I will update my answer for including references to Kendo UI documentation.